# Translate a marker along a path

Tags: html, xml, graphics, svg

In SVG, is it possible to translate the `marker_start` / `marker_end` along a `Path`?

`<path id="e:3" fill="black" fill-opacity="1.0" stroke="black" stroke-opacity="1.0" stroke-width="1" d=" M2 12 L18 17 z" marker-start="url(#markerStart)">`

I'd like to translate `marker-start` some X units along the path.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your marker's `refX` and `refY` attributes, which define where the marker should be attached to the path. For more details see the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#MarkerElementRefXAttribute).

Possibly you will also need to adjust the `viewBox` on the <marker> element. And you can draw outside the viewBox if you need, provided you set `overflow:visible` on the <marker> element (or alternatively specify large enough values in the `markerWidth`, `markerHeight` attributes).